# How to put the page number when printing a web page

Tags: html, css

Using an html table I create a header for my document, I would like to know how I can put the page number when printing the web page, I know with @page selector of css i can configure the content of the margins and others, but I don't know how it does what I want.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIQQl.jpg)

this is the html code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="DocManual.aspx.cs" Inherits="Presentacion.GestionDocumental.DocManual" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link href="../css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/confAPA.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="font-family: 'Times New Roman'">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        
        <div class="hoja" style="text-align:center">
            <h1 style="margin-top: 150px;">Centro médico crecer.</h1>
            <h1 style="margin-top: 120px;">Manual de xxxxxx</h1>
            <h3 style="margin-top: 120px">Versión 1</h3>
            <h1 style="margin-top: 120px">01-01-1990</h1>
        </div>
        

        <div class="hoja" id="tbContenido">
            <h3 style="text-align: center">Tabla de contenido</h3>
            <div>
                <div><span>Introdución</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Objetivos</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Alcance</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Marco Legal</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Desarrollo</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Contenido</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Gosario de terminos</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div><span>Anexos</span></div>
                <div></div>
                <div><span>1</span></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr id="header">
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" rowspan="4">
                                    <img src="../Images/logocrecer.png" width="100" />
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="10" rowspan="3"><strong><span id="lbProceso" runat="server"></span></strong></td>
                                <td colspan="5"><strong>Código:</strong><span id="lbCodigo1" runat="server"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>

                                <td colspan="5"><strong>Fecha:</strong><span id="lbFecha1" runat="server"></span></td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5"><strong>Version:</strong><span id="lbVersion1" runat="server"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="10"><strong><span id="lbProcedimiento" runat="server"></span></strong></td>

                                <td colspan="5"><strong>Páginas:</strong><span id="lbPAginas1" runat="server"></span></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3>Introducción</h3>
                        <div id="txtIntroducion" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Objetivos</h3>
                        <div id="txtOjetivos" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Alcance</h3>
                        <div id="txtAlcance" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Marco Legal</h3>
                        <div id="txtMarcoLegal" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Desarrollo</h3>
                        <div id="txtDesarrollo" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Contenido</h3>
                        <div id="txtContenido" runat="server"></div>

                        <h3>Gosario de terminos</h3>
                        <div></div>

                        <h3>Anexos</h3>
                        <div id="anexos" runat="server"></div>
                        <br />
                        <table id="control-cambios">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="5" class="text-center" style="font-weight:900">CONTROL DE CAMBIOS</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td><strong>Vesion:</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Fecha:</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Justificación</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Descripción</strong></td>
                                    <td><strong>Responsable</strong></td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tbControlCambios" runat="server">
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr id="footer">
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Eleborado por</td>
                                    <td>Revisado por</td>
                                    <td>Aprobado por</td>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody runat="server" id="Participantes" style="text-align:Center">

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script>
        print();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

the print.css archive

```
@media print {

    * {
        color: #000 !important;
        -webkit-text-shadow: none !important;
        text-shadow: none !important;
        font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
        box-shadow: none !important;
    }

    header, nav, footer {
        overflow: visible;
    }

    .body {
        width: auto;
        border: 0;
        margin: 0 5%;
        padding: 0;
        float: none !important;
    }


    a, a:link, a:visited {
        &[href]:after

{
    content: " (" attr(href) ") ";
    font-size: 90%;
}

&[href^="javascript:"],
&[href^="#"] {
    &:after

{
    content: attr();
}

}
}

abbr[title]:after {
    content: " (" attr(title) ")";
}

pre,
blockquote {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

thead {
    display: table-header-group;
}

tr,
img, table {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
}

img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}

@page {
    margin: 2.54cm;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}

p,
h2,
h3 {
    orphans: 3;
    widows: 3;
}

h2,
h3 {
    page-break-after: avoid;
}

#content {
    display: table;
}

#pageFooter {
    display: table-footer-group;
}

    #pageFooter:after {
        counter-increment: page;
        content: "Pagina " counter(page);
        left: 0;
        top: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        z-index: 20;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #cccccc);
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Did you try setting the body position to relative and then adding your page number with absolute positioning?

Comment: CChoma, thanks for your help, I haven't tried, could you tell me how to do it?